# I just tried to write a playbook same error in every playbook

Tags: ansible

```
--- # this is first playbook with handler
- host: demo
  user: ansible
  become: yes
  connection: ssh
  vars:
          pkgname: httpd
  task:
          - name: install httpd service
            action: yum name='{{pkgname}}' state=installed
            notify: restart httpd
  handler:
          - name: restart httpd
            action: service name=httpd state=restarted
```

---

```
ERROR! 'task' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/handler.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

--- # this is first playbook with handler
- host: demo
  ^ here
```

Comment: Modify your questions because is not readable. And use `tasks` instead `task`.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is `tasks:` (plural), not `task:`